# What is the difference in const-correctness between C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, constants, language-design, const-correctness

I understand what const correctness means and my question is not about what const correctness is. So I am not expecting an explanation or C++-FAQ links for that.

My questions are:

- **What are the semantic differences between `const` in C and `const` in C++?** and
- **What is the reason for the difference?**

Quotes from the respective standards which make the differences clear would be nice to have.

I regularly switch between C and C++ and I would like to know the important points that one should keep in mind while doing so.

I don't seem to remember the reason for these (special thanks if you can provide a reasoning) but from the top of my mind, I can remember:

- const variables in C++ have internal linkage by default, while in C they have default external linkage;
- const objects can be used as compile-time values in C++, but cannot be used as compile-time values in C;
- Pointers to string literals must be an `char const*` in C++ but in C it can be `char*`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Pointer to an String literals must be an const in c++: do you mean `char *const` or `char const*`?

Comment: @Als: In early days of C, there was no `const`, so many programs were written assuming that `"Hello, World"` was of type `char[]` when it is of type `char const[]` (and thus decays to `char const*`. I think most compilers just didn't want to force people adding `const` everywhere (by default), but the `-pedantic` flag should report those violations.

Comment: @Matthieu: Also, those are only actually violations on a C++11 implementation. In C++03 there's a deprecated conversion from narrow string literals to `char*` (4.2/2), which as far as I can see has been removed in C++11. So C++03 string literals were of type "array of n const char", but nevertheless could decay to `char*`. Implementations don't have to warn about use of deprecated features, although gcc does by default since `-Wwrite-strings` is on by default for C++.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: String literals are still of type `char[]` in C.

Comment: @Als: how much do you want to get into? In the libraries, for example, C++ has separate const and non-const versions of `strchr` and friends, while C doesn't. The reason is that C doesn't have function overloading and can't be bothered with defining two different functions, so instead it has a single const-incorrect function. Does that count as a difference between constants in C and C++?

Comment: @SteveJessop: I agree the Question is a bit open ended.My motive behind the Q is to identify the differences which might usually matter/make a substantial difference when switching to & fro between C/C++. For ex: Many a programers are blissfully unaware of the `const char *`.Knowing the semantics behind why the difference(as you quoted) would really help.I am not looking at utility library functions differences per se which c++ has been forced to modify for its own semantics.

Comment: "const objects can be used as compile-time values in C++, but cannot be used as compile-time values in C"? In C, `const int=3;` can compile into a literal in assembly. This contradicts this claim  (or I misunderstand it).

Comment: @ugoren: the compiler is allowed to use the value if it knows it, but the language does not permit a `const int` variable in the places that a constant value is called for (such as for the size of a non-VLA array, or the value of a case label). C++ defines "integer constant expressions" for such purposes, and a const-qualified object with a visible definition is permitted in addition to the things that C permits (just literals and enum values, I think, and arithmetic expressions involving only them).

Comment: @ugoren: Consider: `const int n = 5; struct x { int f : n; }; int main() {}`. This is valid C++, not valid C.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I just made a small edit to it. It referred to "constants" in C and C++, but the question is actually about `const`, which is a different thing. `const` really means "read-only", whereas a *constant* is a literal, and a *constant expression* is one that can be evaluated at compile time. (Although in C++, but not in C, a `const` declaration can create a constant expression; for example, given `const int x = 42;`, the identifier `x` is a constant expression in C++.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In addition to the differences you cite, and the library differences that
Steve Jessop mentions,

```
char* p1;
char const* const* p2 = &p1;
```

is legal in C++, but not in C.  Historically, this is because C
originally allowed:

```
char* p1;
char const** p2 = &p1;
```

Shortly before the standard was adopted, someone realized that this
punched a hole in const safety (since `*p2` can now be assigned a
`char const*`, which results in `p1` being assigned a `char const*`); with
no real time to analyse the problem in depth, the C committee banned any
additional `const` other than top level const.  (I.e. `&p1` can be
assigned to a `char **` or a `char **const`, but not to a `char const**`
nor a `char const* const*`.)  The C++ committee did the further
analysis, realized that the problem was only present when a `const`
level was followed by a non-`const` level, and worked out the necessary
wording.  (See §4.4/4 in the standard.)

Comment: @Norswap They break const-correctness because they allow an expression which modifies a const object without an explicit type conversion: `int const i = 42; int const* pi = &i; int* pi2; int const** ppi = &pi2; pii = pi; *pi2 = 0;`.  The last line breaks const-correctness.  This example was discovered at the very end of C standardization; as a result, C banned all implicit addition of top level const.  When standardizing C++, one person did a more complete analysis, and the rule was liberalized to allow adding top level const as long as all nested levels were also const.

Comment: Damn, once again I got tricked by the misleading formatting (there really ought to be a space before the star in `const*`)... just after pointing it out. Shame on me.

Comment: Why not write `const int i = 42`? You keep saying `int const i = 42` but no one will write like that.

Comment: Regarding your 4 upvoted comment: I assume you meant `const int i = 42; const int *pi = &i; int *pi2; const int **ppi = &pi2; ppi = &pi; *pi2 = 0;` (should be `ppi` not `pii`, there is no `pii`) when you wrote `pii`, and it's `ppi = &pi` not `ppi = pi` since they're pointer to different targets, `const in *` for `ppi` and `const int` for `pi`, respectively.

Comment: `const int i = 42;` is inconsistent. The coding guidelines where I current work recommend `int const i = 42;`, and that's been the form I've encountered most frequently over the last 20 years.

Answer (score 12):

In C `const` declarations do not produce constant expressions, i.e. in C you can't use a `const int` object in a case label, as a bit-field width or as array size in a non-VLA array declaration (all this is possible in C++). Also, const objects have external linkage by default in C (internal linkage in C++).
Const-correctness rules of C++ language support the following standard conversion

```
int **pp = 0;
const int *const *cpp = pp; // OK in C++

int ***ppp = 0;
int *const *const *cppp = ppp; // OK in C++
```

These will not work in c.

Comment: In C, if I have `void f(void **p);`, I can't do `const int *x; f(&x);`  (if `f` used the return value instead of an output parameter, there would be no problem). Does your example mean this code is OK in C++?

Answer (score 7):

The reason for some of these differences is to allow us to get rid of preprocessor macros, which was one of Bjarne's early design goals.

In C we might have

```
 #define MAX_FOOS 10
 int foos[MAX_FOOS];
```

In C++ we'd prefer to be able to write

```
 const int max_foos = 10;
 int foos[max_foos];
```

For that to work `max_foos` needs to be usable in a constant expression. It also needs to have internal linkage, so the definition can appear in a header without causing multiple definition errors, and more importantly to make it easier for the compiler to not allocate any storage for `max_foos`.

When the C committee adopted const from C++ they didn't adopt the antipathy to macros, so they didn't need these semantics.