# Incompatible pointer assignment

Tags: c

I've recently tried to write code like the following:

```
extern bool f(const char *const *b);
// SNIP
char *d[] = {/* SNIP */};
char *c[] = {/* SNIP */};
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(d)/sizeof(char *); i++) {
    c[1] = d[i];
    f(c); // WARNING
}
```

So this gives a warning along the lines of
“you can't assign `char **` to `const char *const *`”.

I can see why it's illegal to assign `char **` to `const char **`:

```
const char *f = "cats";
const char **fp;
char *g;
fp = &g;         // Let's pretend it's legal to assign char ** to const char **
*fp = f;         // OK, assigning const char * to const char *
*g--;            // OK, decrementing char -- but g == f!
printf("%s", f); // Prints "bats"
```

But this can't happen if we assign a `char **` to a `const char *const *`:

```
const char *f = "cats";
const char *const *fp = &f;
char *g;
fp = &g;         // Let's pretend it's legal to assign char ** to const char *const *
*fp = f;         // Illegal, assigning const char * to const char *const
*g--;            // OK, decrementing char -- but g == f!
printf("%s", f); // Prints "bats" (though it won't compile)
```

So the question is why this requirement exists, given that it won't cause issues.

(FWIW, I'm using C99. Apparently C++11 allows this.)

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message? There's almost certainly duplicate questions, but I can't find one.

Comment: It looks like you should be able to use `extern bool f(char * const * b);`

Answer (score 0):

This is an oversight in the language design, it only allows implicit addition of `const` at the first level.

You'll have to either use a cast or change the function parameter type.

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8909208/1505939)