# Why is there no duplicate definition error when I define a `const int` in header file?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, extern

Apologies if this has been asked before. I searched the internet and did not find an answer.

Say I have a file `Common.h`, and `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` include `Common.h`.

If I want to have a global `const char *` in the `Common` translation unit, I must make it `extern` in `Common.h`, and define it in `Common.cpp`. Otherwise, if I simply define `const char * MSG = "Hello World";` in `Common.h`, I get a `duplicate symbol` error during compilation.

However, if I simply define a global const int in `Common.h` with a statement like `const int CONSTANT = 10;` then the code compiles without a duplicate symbol error, and everything works fine.

I am confused as to why this is the case. It seems to me here that the only difference between the two examples above is the type, which I think shouldn't make a difference. Why do I get the duplicate symbol error for C-strings, but not ints?

Suppose `main.cpp`, `A.h`, `B.h`, `A.cpp`, and `B.cpp` look as follows:

```
// A.h
#pragma once
void f();
```

```
// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "Common.h"

#include <iostream>

void f() {
    std::cout << MSG << std::endl;
}
```

```
// B.h
#pragma once
void g();
```

```
// B.cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "Common.h"

#include <iostream>

void g() {
    std::cout << CONSTANT << std::endl;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    f();
    g();
}
```

Now, suppose we take compile with the command `g++ main.cpp A.cpp B.cpp Common.cpp -std=c++14`.

If we make `Common.h` and `Common.cpp` the following, then compilation fails with error `duplicate symbol MSG`:

```
// Common.h
#pragma once
const char * MSG = "Hello World";
const int CONSTANT = 10; // defined in header file
```

```
// Common.cpp
// empty
```

However, this compiles:

```
// Common.h
#pragma once
extern const char * MSG;
const int CONSTANT = 10; // defined in header file
```

```
// Common.cpp
#include "Common.h"
const char * MSG = "Hello World";
```

I am wondering why we need extern and to separate definition & declaration for the string, but not for the int.

Someone suggested making the C-string type as `const char * const` instead of `const char *`. Why does making the pointer const work? Also, in this case, what is the difference between this solution and the solution I provided above (where we make the string extern instead and split definition/declaration)? Why do both methods solve the compilation error and what is the difference between the methods?

I noticed also that if I turn `const int` into just `int`, then I get the `duplicate symbol` error again. I feel like the reason behind this is related to the answer to my questions above. Why is this the case?

Comment: Nothing describes code quite like well-written code.

Comment: `const char *MSG` means a non-const variable called `MSG` . The `const` is part of the pointed-to type .

Comment: please do not tag unrelated languages. C++ and C are distinct languages with distinct rules. yout program seems to be written in C++

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have provided the code

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The concepts I am asking about apply to both C and C++

Comment: @TonyBai This is exactly one of there areas where c++ and c differs.

Comment: @4386427 How so? Can you please explain?

Comment: @TonyBai I guess you find many descriptions on SO. Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923016/4386427

Comment: @TonyBai there is no "apply to both C and C++" except for the thin line of *this C stuff that goes into headers should compile in C++* and *this C stuff should be linkable with C++ stuff*. Since your question does not have any files with `.c` extension, this question has nothing to do with C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the differences of C and C++.

In C++ a `const` variable is implicitly `static`, i.e. only visible to the current translation unit. In C it is implicitly `extern` so visible to the entire program (which is also the default for the other non-const declararions in both C and C++).

This explains your observation.

Note: A `const char *p` declaration of a variable is not a `const` variable. It means it *points* to a const variable (i.e. `*p` is cannot be modified), but `p` itself is not `const`. So behavior here is different. `const char * const p` would be a const declaration.

Comment: That makes sense. Answers all of my questions above. Thanks!