# Why do some libs use non-const char * as function argument?

Tags: c++, c, libs

Sometimes using pure-C libs in my C++ projects, I see strange (in my opinion) function declarations.

E.g.: libldap's **ldap_search_ext()**: https://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_search_ext_s

```
int ldap_search_ext(
       LDAP *ld,
       char *base,
       int scope,
       char *filter,
       char *attrs[], // this one!
       int attrsonly,
       LDAPControl **serverctrls,
       LDAPControl **clientctrls,
       struct timeval *timeout,
       int sizelimit,
       int *msgidp );
```

Why can't attrs[] be a `const char *`?

Declarations like this don't want to change the content of the pointer and generate a lot of issues:

```
// pure C
void func(char * data[])
{
  ...
}

func({"blabla"}); // won't work (corrected: yes, this is wrong syntax, but it's true for structs of pointers)

const char *d[] = {"blabla", "blablu"};
func(d); // won't work

// C++
const std::string str("blabla");
char * data[] = { str.data() }; // even non-const won't work (because data() returns const*)
/// etc...
```

Is there any reason for not declaring such arguments as const?

Comment: Added `C++`  (rare case where both `C` & `C++`  tags are appropriately used in same question.)

Comment: OpenLDAP is a very old, established, library. It was written back in the days where `const`-correctness was not a de-facto requirement. In this case, it *should* be a `const` pointer.

Comment: `char *attrs[]` is essentially the same thing as `char **attrs`, and `const char**` does not behave like you'd intuitively expect, so it might have something to do with that.

Comment: Fwiw, `const d = {"blabla", "blablu"};`  won't work regardless (yes, I have implicit-int disabled). Regardless, in remotely modern code there is *zero* reason for not properly const-izing pointers of *any* type when the pointed to data is considered immutable.

Comment: BTW, `func({"blabla"});` is not pure C, because you would need a compound literal there.

Comment: Being a little bit more pedantic, the correct definition would actually be `char const * const *attrs`

Comment: of course I meant `const char *d[] = {"blabla", "blablu"};`

this should work since C99 if I remember correctly.. Haven't written in C since years..

Comment: Lookup `ritchie strchr` for a bit of a background on ways in which const is a poor concept in C.  Probably in C++ too; ref `thompson c++`.   Notably, the plan9 C compiler includes a default equivalent to '-Dconst=' to alleviate the problems.

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908071/const-correctness-in-c-vs-c

Answer (score 5):

This is mostly just (due to) a historical wart in the C standard that has never been fixed.

When `const` was added to C, the ability to implictly (and safely) convert simple pointers was added -- you can implicitly convert a `T *` to a `const T *` just fine.  However, (safe) conversion of more complex pointer types was missed -- you can't convert a `T * const *` to a `const T * const *`.  As a result, when a library takes a double pointer like this, it does not have any 'good' way of making it `const` if it is read only.  Making it either a `const char **` or a `const char * const *` would break some uses (requiring messy explicit casts).

Note that allowing implicit conversions of `T **` to `const T **` would be unsafe -- such a pointer could be used to modify a `T *` to point at a `const T *` without a cast.

Answer (score 4):

One likely reason is that string constants in C (unlike C++) are not `const`.

As such, there was a historical lack of const-correctness in many libraries that should have been there.  Had string constants been `const`, programmers would have been forced to account for it.

When dealing with libraries such as this that you know don't modify the argument, you have to apply a `const_cast` to make it fit.

```
char *d[] = {const_cast<char *>("blabla"), const_cast<char *>("blablu")};
func(d);

const std::string str("blabla");
char * data[] = { const_cast<char *>(str.data()) };
func(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, sure. I always use this solution, My question was more about the reasons of the libs developers.
I've also seen it in STM Library and always interpreted it as low code quality.